# Stripping tables using bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

So I have the following web-pages:

http://dservuk.tns-global.com/TNSMLBofA-dec3c1fd-0bed-4505-9c4b-869c4efc19a1/FM/May2015-031ea442-6906-4e1d-963e-c02bbce6c7a9/mltables.html?section=SCA#tables

http://dservuk.tns-global.com/TNSMLBofA-dec3c1fd-0bed-4505-9c4b-869c4efc19a1/FM/May2015-031ea442-6906-4e1d-963e-c02bbce6c7a9/mltables.html?section=SCA#tables

I would like to strip only the table into a data-frame or some other kind of structure I can then play with with the ultimate goal being that I can loop through similar web-pages easily and then concatenate all the results such that I can place them into a spreadsheet.

I'm getting completely lost and tutorials all point me to dated libraries. I am using Python 3.4 and PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3. Let us just assume I have no current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use something like `Selenium` to get hold of the HTML for the website you are trying to access, as it requires Javascript to generate the page. The following should help to get you started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

url = 'http://dservuk.tns-global.com/TNSMLBofA-dec3c1fd-0bed-4505-9c4b-869c4efc19a1/FM/May2015-031ea442-6906-4e1d-963e-c02bbce6c7a9/mltables.html?section=SCA#tables'

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary())
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
browser.quit()

for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='mrTable')[1:]:
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        print [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
```

This would display each row as follows:

```
[u'', u'Breakdown']
[u'', u'Global Specialists Only', u'Regional Specialists with a Global View', u'Regional Specialists Only', u'Global Total', u'GEM Specialists', u'Regional Total', u'Grand Total']
[u' ', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'Chief Investment Officer', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'11%', u'13%', u'11%', u'11%', u'33%', u'12%', u'12%']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'Asset Allocator / Strategist / Economist', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'41%', u'25%', u'8%', u'36%', u'0%', u'19%', u'31%']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'Portfolio Manager', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'40%', u'55%', u'61%', u'45%', u'67%', u'57%', u'48%']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'Other', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'8%', u'7%', u'19%', u'8%', u'0%', u'12%', u'10%']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much Martin. Unfortunately the code does not compile on my machine. I do not have Firefox installed. Is there a Chrome or IE alternative? I am also running 64-bit python on a 64-bit machine if that is of any importance.

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible using Chrome, I've not tried it though. I'm also running 64bit Python. Installation can be a little fiddly but it is definitely useful.